# Return -1 when I run mysqli_affected_rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to avoid inserting duplicated date into my db. so I write a function called avoid_redundant(). this function has to check if the data is existed  or not. when it's existed return false and prevent to be inserted. I was digging on the Internet to find out why mysqli_affected_rows() returns -1 but find about query. my query is ok. I'm so confused.

here is my simple code.

```
<?php

class Database{
      private username;
      private pass;
      private database;
      private server;

     public function __constructor(){
          $this->username='root';
          $this->pass='';
          $this->database='myDb';
          $this->server='localhost';
     }
    public function init(){
          $link=mysqli_connect($this->server,$this->username,$this->pass,$this->database) or die('unable to connect'. mysqil_error());
          if ($link)
              return $link;
    }

    public function avoid_redundant($title,$desc){
          $link=$this->init();
          $query='SELECT * FROM mytbl WHERE title LIKE "%'.$title.'%" AND desc LIKE "%'.$desc.'%"';
          $result=mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
          $row=mysqli_affected_rows($link);
          if($row>0)
            return FALSE;
            return TRUE;
    }

}
// IN THE MAIN 


$db= new Database();
$title=mysqli_real_escape_string(//mytitle);
$desc=mysqli_real_escape_string(//mydescription);
if($db->avoid_redundat($title,$desc)){
   //do the rest.....
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you try to re-read the mysqli_affected_rows() function's description in the PHP manual?

Comment: @YourCommonSense. why did you give a down mark? I read again. what's wring with my question??

Comment: Try to read one more time. There is very little reading actually, scarcely a few words.

Comment: @YourCommonSense. check this link [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_affected_rows.asp)

Comment: @YourCommonSense The manual says **For SELECT statements mysqli_affected_rows() works like mysqli_num_rows().** So his code *should* work.

Comment: Well, it's my bad then. My apologies

Comment: You have a typo: `mysqli_qurey` should be `mysqli_query`. Is that in the real code, or a copying error?

Comment: @Barmar. it's not in my real code. just miss type here

Comment: You seem to do that a lot. It would be better if you used copy and paste instead of retyping.

Answer (score 1):

You have not made any query that has affect on the db.

The relevant function for checking if any results returned from a SELECT query is:

```
mysqli_num_rows()
```

That being said you really should consider creating a unique key in the table that defines a unique row and use Mysql option [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) instead of using that functin you made.

Comment: I used mysqli_num_rows() but for some reason that I don't know , for some data it return `0` though it exists in mytbl

Comment: The manual says that `mysqli_affected_rows()` acts like `mysqli_num_rows()` when it's a `SELECT` query. So it's supposed to work.

Comment: print the actual query and make sure it actually returns data in phpMyadmin / workbench